# Static assert that method cannot be called from constructor or destructor

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
template <typename SELF>
class Base {
protected:
    template <int X>
    void foo();
};

class Child : public Base<Child> {
public:
    Child() {
        //I want this to throw a static assertion failure
        foo<10>();
    }
    ~Child() {
        //Should also static assert here
    }
};
```

Is there any way I make the compiler throw a compile-time assertion failure if the templated member method foo() is called within the constructor or destructor?  In other words, I want to prevent, at compile time, the method from being called within the constructor or destructor.

Please don't ask why foo is a template; this is just a simplified example of a more complex project.

Comment: At the very least, as far as constructor goes, the problem is that as far as `Base` is concerned, it is done with initialization at that point, and that's a fundamental predicate the language relies on.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What problem would this capability solve?  And which constructors would qualify as "the constructor"?

Comment: I can't see a way to do it at compile time, but it would be easy to `assert` at runtime (and unit testing should catch this).

Comment: @PaulSanders I'd be curious to see how you'd go about doing that at runtime without support code in the `Child` class. I could perhaps see it if a vtable was involved, but OP's code doesn't use one.

Comment: @DrewDormann In my more complex code, the method I do not want to be called "notifies" the Child object's "parent" object that it should be deleted.  If I call this from the constructor, the destructor will get called before the constructor exits.

Comment: @PatrickWright if I understand your situation, it seems very similar to "How do I prevent `delete this;` in a constructor or destructor?"

Comment: @PatrickWright You are jumping through a lot of hoops to make `delete this;` (or the equivalent) work, when you really should never be doing such a thing in the first place for a variety of different reasons. I'm going to speculate a bit and add: You are severely overestimating the overhead incurred by a vtable.

Comment: @Frank I think you just helped make something click in my head.  I didn't even realize this was what I was doing.  I think I need to re-evaluate my design...

Comment: It's a tricky problem, because even if `foo<10>();` were called in **some other** member function, you now have to ensure that **that** function is not called from the constructor or destructor.  You're effectively trying to inspect the full call stack at compile time.

Comment: @Frank Sure, you do of course need to _make_ it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the OP has acknowledged in the comments that the whole endeavour is probably misguided in their case, the question remains an interesting puzzle.

Performing such a check at runtime is feasible, but it needs to involve code that runs *after* `Child` during construction, and code that runs *before* `Child` during destruction.

One way to do this would to sandwich `Child` between `Base` and some other utility class. For example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>

template<typename SELF>
struct Activator final : SELF {

#ifndef NDEBUG
  Activator() {
    SELF* self = static_cast<SELF*>(this);
    self->alive_state_ = true;
  }

  ~Activator() {
    SELF* self = static_cast<SELF*>(this);
    self->alive_state_= false;
  }
#endif

};

template <typename SELF>
class Base {

#ifndef NDEBUG
  friend class Activator<SELF>;
  std::atomic<bool> alive_state_= false;
#endif

public:
  Base() {}

protected:
  template <int X>
  void foo() {
    assert(alive_state_);
  }
};

class ChildImpl : public Base<ChildImpl> {
public:
  ChildImpl() {
    // fails at runtime
    //foo<10>(); 
  }
  ~ChildImpl() {
    // fails at runtime
    //foo<10>();
  }

  void bar() {
    foo<10>();
  }
};

using Child = Activator<ChildImpl>;

int main() {
  Child child;
  child.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

This will correctly catch any and invocation of `foo<>()` during construction/destruction, no matter how convoluted the indirection to the call is.

You can check it out on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/szo6Mhef4

Answer (score 3):

This solution works only with C++20, only for destructor, and it is not compile time. I also not sure that it works everywhere. I don't recommend to use it in production code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <cassert>

template <typename SELF>
class Base {
protected:
    template <int X>
    void foo(std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
    {
        assert(std::string_view(location.function_name()).find("::~") == std::string::npos);

        std::cout << location.function_name() << '\n';
    }
};

class Child : public Base<Child> {
public:
    Child() {
        //I want this to throw a static assertion failure
        foo<10>();
    }
    ~Child() {
        //Should also static assert here
        foo<10>();
    }
};

int main() {
    Child child;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this has quite a few drawbacks (including not working if `foo<>` is called from a function called by the destructor), I just want to say that this is a really neat an creative way to tackle this.

Comment: @DrewDormann I have tested it and it works when you pass source_location in arguments function names are "Child::Child()" and "Child::~Child()" . I compiled it with g++ 12

Comment: @Sandro - confirmed, you are correct.